# Is it possible to lock all the threads on a CPU from a C program?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to figure out if I would be able to create pthreads (or some alternative) so that my program controlled all the threads in my system. I don't know if it is a possibility or not. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to somehow associate those pthreads with the actual kernel level threads on the system.Research into kernel level threads vs user level threads.Im sure its possible but definitely not trivial.